# User values are accurate until alert function of jQuery but the saveorupdate function persist null values in db table

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, hibernate, spring-mvc

During the alert function of jQuery the values are alerted as what user has given as input but somehow in database table the values are persisted as `null`. Could anyone please tell me what am I doing wrong or what's causing this?

Could anyone please tell me, is it wrong to bind the jQuery inside the JavaScript `else` statement, but if so, when I alert the values, it should be giving `null` as values but the jQuery function alerts the user inputs accurately or is it the AJAX, that's passing the `null` values or is there a problem in the controller class that needs any modification. Thanks!

JavaScript function to validate and jQuery to bind and send data:

```
function validate2() {
  var R_name = document.getElementById("R_name").value;
  var R_email = document.getElementById("R_email").value;
  var R_number = document.getElementById("R_number").value;
  var R_pass = document.getElementById("R_pass").value;
  var R_password = document.getElementById("Rc_pass").value;
  var re = /[0-9]/;
  var atposition = R_email.indexOf("@");
  var dotposition = R_email.lastIndexOf(".");

  if (R_name == "" || R_email == "" || R_number == "" || R_pass == "" || R_password == "") {
    alert("please fill the form");
  } else if (R_name.length < 3) {
    alert("name is too short");
  } else if (atposition < 1 || (dotposition - atposition < 2))
  /* if user gives email which starts with @ or if there is no words inbetween (@) and (.)  */
  {
    alert("Please enter correct email ID");
  } else if (R_number.length < 6) {
    alert("number is too short");
  } else if (R_pass.length < 8) {
    alert("password should have minimum 8 characters");
  } else if (!re.test(R_pass)) {
    alert("Error: password must contain at least one number (0-9)!");
  } else if (R_password !== R_pass) {
    alert("passwords do not match");
  } else {
    $(function() { // this function will load on submit//
      alert(R_name);
      alert(R_email);
      alert(R_number);
      alert(R_pass);
      alert(R_password);
      $.ajax({ // defining the below function as ajax responsive//
        url: 'saveOrUpdate', // the function that process the  mapped url name and matching type is going to receive the data//
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
          R_name,
          R_number,
          R_email,
          R_pass
        }, // function to get the value from jsp page and send it to mapped class function//
        success: function(response) { // if the backend process is success then the function will run by getting the response as its parameter//
          alert(response.message);
        }
      });
    });
  }
}
```

Spring MVC controller, which receives the data and forwards it to `UserServices` class to persist data:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/saveOrUpdate", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody Map<String, Object> getSaved(Users users) {
  Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();

  if (userServices.saveOrUpdate(users)) {
    map.put("status", "200");
    map.put("message", "Your record have been saved successfully");
  }

  return map;
}
```

HTML:

```
<section class="signup-section">
  <div class="login">
    <form action="">
      <!-- on registration i have to put the url of the backend class to handle it -->
      <ul class="ul-list">
        <li><input type="text" required class="input" placeholder="Your Name" id="R_name" /><span class="icon"><i class="fa fa-user" style="font-size:20px"></i></span></li>
        <li><input type="number" required class="input" placeholder="Your Number (no plus or minus signs)" id="R_number" pattern="('^\\d+$')" title="Must contain only numbers" required/><span class="icon"><i class="fa fa-mobile-phone" style="font-size:25px"></i></span></li>
        <li><input type="email" required class="input" placeholder="Your Email" id="R_email" /><span class="icon"><i class="fa fa-envelope" style="font-size:15px"></i></span></li>
        <li><input type="password" placeholder="Password" required class="input" id="R_pass" pattern="(?=.*?[0-9]).{8,}" title="Must contain at least one number and at least 8 or more characters" required/><span class="icon"><i class="fa fa-lock" style="font-size:20px" ></i></span></li>
        <li><input type="password" placeholder="Retype Password" required class="input" id="Rc_pass" pattern="(?=.*?[0-9]).{8,}" title="Must contain at least one number and at least 8 or more characters" required/><span class="icon"><i class="fa fa-lock" style="font-size:20px" ></i></span></li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" id="check1"> <label for="check1">I accept terms and conditions</label></li>
        <li><input type="submit" value="SIGN UP" class="btn" onclick="validate2()"></li>
      </ul>
    </form>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After roughly inspecting your code I think the following line contains the error:

```
data:{R_name,R_number,R_email,R_pass}
```

As you are passing the `data` to the `servlet` which is reading the data in `object` format so you need to assign the keys to your `parameters` and read them using `request.getParameter('keyName')`. So try using the following:

```
data:{name:R_name,number:R_number,email:R_email,pass:R_pass}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for going through the code i tried your suggestion but still the values are persisted only as null,im greatfull for your suggestion though

Comment: you were correct i forgot to include the key sir and one other bug was i had an input named user_number that was of type integer and my map can only accept sting and object type so i changed to user_number to string type and made sure the variable names in my pojo and key values are same and it worked sir!!!! thanks a lot sir, you are amazing!! thank you so much for helping me i could not show my gratitude enough again thanks a lot sir.